# Moving Windows Between Multiple Monitors (Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon)

Tags: linux-mint, multiple-monitors, cinnamon, window-manager

[image: Monitor Setup]

My monitor setup is as described by the diagram above. Previously, using the move-window-to-monitor shortcut(s) (`Super+Shift+{arrow direction}`) I was able to move a window to whatever monitor was adjacent/above/below. However, now, I am unable to move a window from the main widescreen monitor (#4 in the diagram) to the top-right monitor (#2 in the diagram)- using the `Super+Shift+UpArrow` hotkey will only move the window in question to the top-left monitor (#3 in the diagram).

Is there any fix for this? Being unable to move a window to one out of four monitors varies in the range of slightly-to-extremely annoying. Cinnamon DE has a "Move Window to Monitor #*n*" functionality, but it's only accessible via right-clicking the window on the taskbar and selecting a monitor- I'd even accept mapping this functionality for specific windows to a set of specific hotkeys, but so far I've been unable to find any information on how to go about doing this. Thank you for any help provided, I'm greatly appreciative!

I've tried rearranging the top two monitors (#3 and #1, respectively) to be closer together, further apart, etc., as well as swapping the "primary" monitor, but so far, nothing has worked.